# Distinction between four non-orthogonal quantum states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, hilbert-space, measurements

Given an unknown qubit $|\psi\rangle$. It is promised to be in one of four possible states: $|0\rangle$, $|1\rangle$, $|+\rangle$ or $|-\rangle$,

where
$|+\rangle$ = $(|0\rangle$+ $|1\rangle)/\sqrt2$ and $|-\rangle$ = $(|0\rangle$- $|1\rangle)/\sqrt2$.

If a single copy of $|\psi\rangle$ is provided, then direct measurement will not give any useful information.

The question is: If $N$ copies of $|\psi\rangle$ are provided. What is the  maximum probability to find the state of $|\psi\rangle$ based on the $N$ copies using direct measurements only?

Comment: Hello Ahmed and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! As it currently stands, your question looks like an artificially constructed exercise, or some homework. We prefer that if you ask a question like that, you provide what you did to try to solve the problem, and ask a more *conceptual* question, as we are not a homework help service. Best of luck with your question!

Comment: @heather  Political correctness be dammed, you are a credit to this site since you joined,  Heather.

Comment: @Countto10 thank you! I'm on a reviewing spree right now =) It's good to see you around.

Comment: @heather Thanks for your comment. It is not a homework for sure. It is related to QKD. In  the BB84 protocol, for example, the key is encoded this way. I was just wondering if Alice sends N copies of every qubit. Can this help Eve to read the whole key, and with what probability?

Comment: @AhmedYounes even if it isn't homework, it is an "exercise", if you see what I mean - a problem that must be worked, whether assigned by an instructor or not. I would update your question with that information.

Comment: I feel like I have now seen about a thousand people respond to "this violates our policies on homework-like questions" with "this isn't homework!" without understanding that we really don't care how *you came to it*, we care about *what it is*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An optimal measurement to classify between those four states, given $n$ copies, will fail with probability somewhere between $2^{-n-1}$ and $2^{-n+1}$. Probably $2^{-n}$.

I'll go over a simple classification strategy that doesn't do so well, then a better one that achieves $2^{-n+1}$, then show why the failure rate has to be at least $2^{-n-1}$.

## Simple Strategy: Grouping

Split the $n$ qubits into two groups of size $n/2$, measure one group along the X axis and the other group along the Z axis. In one group you'll be measuring along the wrong axis and get random results. In the other there will be complete agreement. You figure out if the state is along the Z axis or X axis via which group agrees, and whether the state is along or against that axis by the measurement result the group is agreeing on.

This only fails if the random group happens to agree by chance, which happens with probability $2^{-n/2+1}$. In that case you're forced to guess which group is the right one, but half of the time you'll be right so overall the failure probability is $2^{-n/2}$.

## Near-Optimal Strategy: Control-All

Do a controlled-not operation onto an ancilla qubit initialized to $|0\rangle$, using all $n$ qubits as a control. Now temporarily apply a NOT gate to every qubit and do the controlled-not onto the same ancilla with every input qubit as a control again. In other words, toggle the ancilla in the parts of the superposition where all of the qubits agree (in the computation basis).

If we're in the $|0\rangle^{\otimes n}$ or $|1\rangle^{\otimes n}$ case, the ancilla will definitely be on. If we're in the $|+\rangle^{\otimes n}$ or $|-\rangle^{\otimes n}$ case, there is a $\frac{2}{2^{n}}$ chance that the ancilla will be on. We accept that as a risk of a false classification.

So most of the time the value of the ancilla tells us if we have a Z-axis qubit or an X-axis qubit. We then simply measure all of the qubits along the indicated axis in order to find out whether the qubits' values are along or against the indicated axis. We can boost our chances slightly higher by noticing the qubits disagreeing with each other a lot when the ancilla was on; this indicates that we are measuring along the Z axis by actually we're in the false positive part of the X-axis case.

So this strategy achieves a failure probability of $2^{-n+1}$, and can likely be tweaked into achieving $2^{-n}$.

## Lower Bound on Failure Rate

The trace distance between $|0\rangle^{\otimes n}$ and $|+\rangle^{\otimes n}$ is $1-2^{-n}$. This indicates that an optimal measuring strategy will incorrectly classify between those two states at least $2^{-n-1}$ of the time. The problem you have contains this problem as a sub-case, and so $2^{-n-1}$ is also a lower-bound on the failure rate of classifying between your four states. Therefore the near-optimal strategy is at most a factor of 4 away from optimal.